# Change Woocommerce Storefront Star Rating Color for Product Blocks

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, colors, review

I am using the following code to change the color of star ratings on the product, shop, and search result pages in my Woocommerce Storefront store:

```css
.star-rating span:before,
.star-rating:before {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

However, when I add product blocks (best-sellers, new releases, etc.) to my pages, the star ratings show up as the default black color. How would I change this to a custom color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the css by the `.wc-block-grid__product` class:

```css
.wc-block-grid__product .star-rating span:before,
.star-rating:before {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```